# Django right-join on many-to-one relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset, right-join

In my system, I have and `Account` model that has many `Location`s as follows:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    # ... also contains billing address data

class Location(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account')
    # ... also contains physical address data
```

I want to create a search view that allows the user to search for an `Account` object based on billing address or physical address and display the results in a table with a single `Account` entry for each associated `Location` object. I can't do this with a left-join from the `Account` model; this results in a single entry for each `Account` object and thus doesn't cover all `Location` objects that are associated with an `Account` (I don't care about locations that aren't associated with accounts).

Instead, I want to do this with a right-join from the `Location` model to the `Account` model. That way, all accounts are included at least once and once for each location they are associated with, and every location that is associated with an account is included as well.

Is there a way to do this in Django 1.8+?

Edit: `Account` objects are not required to have associated `Location` objects, and it may be the case in the future that `Location.account is NULL == True` for some `Location` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my goals here can much more easily be reached by taking advantage of Django's `through` declaration for many-to-many relationships. I explicitly define the link table:

```
class AccountLocation(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True)
```

...I then declare the relationship between `Account` and `Location` on the `Account` model:

```
locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, through='AccountLocation')
```

Lastly, I implemented custom `save()` and `delete() logic on the`Account`and`Location`models. The`Account`model automatically puts a one-sided entry into`AccountLocation`whenever a new`Account`instance is created, and the`Location`model removes one-sided entries in the link table when a`Location`instance is created or creates one when the last`Location`linked to an`Account` is deleted.

This solution satisfies all of my requirements because I can then use `AccountLocation` as my search table, there will always be at least one entry in that table for every account, and searches can be run on data from both the `Account` model and the `Location` model at the same time.

Django doesn't support right-joins, but the same result can be achieved by other means.